# Rails - Save Nested Params for Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

My params for a nested form look like this:

```
"answer_group"=>{"539"=>{"answer_text"=>{"Scoreboard Report"=>"0", "GBG Observation"=>"1", "Data Review"=>"1", "Coach Probe"=>"0", "Team Assignment"=>"0", "Probe"=>"0", "Joint Probe"=>"0", "Weekly Scoreboard"=>"0"}}, "556"=>{"1034"=>{"column1"=>"n/o", "column2"=>"1", "column3"=>"is", "column4"=>"this", "column5"=>"working"}, "1035"=>{"column1"=>"n/o", "column2"=>"1", "column3"=>"", "column4"=>"", "column5"=>""}}
```

How do I save and access the nested params if keys are `question.id`?  I have attributes for `column1` ... `column5` in the table, everything else should save to `answer_text`.

Something like `answer_attributes["#{question.id}"]`?

Comment: It would be more readable if you could update your nested_form params hash to be indented accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For saving, take a closer look at `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.  The Rails framework provides a mechanism for doing what you've described.

For accessing, what you have would work but the interpolated string is the same thing as `answer_attributes[question.id.to_s]`, which is arguably more readable.

Hope this helps.